# Pandas, order of groupby and projection

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in Pandas, in that data frame I want to know number of occurrences of each combination of values in two particular columns. The following code seems to do what I want:

```py
coupon_test.groupby(['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME'])[['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']].count()

                            CAPSULE_TEXT  GENRE_NAME
CAPSULE_TEXT    GENRE_NAME      
WEBサービス     その他のクーポン             2           2
...
```

However, if I first do a projection and then group by, it returns an empty result:

```py
coupon_test[['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']].groupby(['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']).count()

CAPSULE_TEXT  GENRE_NAME
```

If I remove count, I will get some results, but they don't appear to be grouped:

```py
coupon_test[['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']].groupby(['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']).head()

    CAPSULE_TEXT    GENRE_NAME
0   グルメ     グルメ
...
```

What is the difference between these two cases? Why would `count()` in the second example not return the same result as the one in the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coupon_test[['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']]` is a DataFrame with *only two columns*.
If you group by these two columns, you have groups with no values. Each group is an empy dataframe:

```
In [77]: pd.DataFrame(index=[[0,1],[2,3]])
Out[77]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(0, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Applying `count` to each of these empty DataFrames results in an empty Series:

```
In [79]: pd.DataFrame(index=[[0,1],[2,3]]).count()
Out[79]: Series([], dtype: int64)
```

Thus, this is a degenerate case, for which `groupby/count` returns nothing. The moral of the story is that when using `groupby/count`, you need at least one column which you are not grouping by so that there is *something to count*.

Comment: Thank you, projecting an extra column helped.